# Can't vertically align ul within li in nav

Tags: css, menu, navigation, html-lists

I'm trying to vertical align a ul(subNav.ul) within an li.

```
 <nav id="nav">
   <ul>
       <li class="subNav"><a href="somePage1.php">Some Page1</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="relatedPage1">Related Page1</a><li>
              <li><a href="relatedPage2">Related Page2</a><li>
          </ul>
       <li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

I was having problems with visibility, but worked that out.  Now I need to get the sub list to align vertically.  Here's the CSS:

```
#nav li.subNav ul {  display: block; visibility: hidden;}|
#nav li.subNav ul li {  display: None;  visibility: hidden;}
#nav li.subNav:hover ul li {  visibility: visible;  display: block; float: left;}
```

'set properties' are #div1 #nav ul = display: inline-block; margin: 0px, auto; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; list-style-type: none;
and #nav li.subNav ul = visibility: hidden; & display: block is overridden. Is there something I can do to this tag to get list items to align vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: Please create a working code snippet.

Comment: what do you mean snippet.  how do I do that?  Or are us just asking for more detail?

Comment: Here is the custom style-sheet. http://jsfiddle.net/jzeig1/k4gx33nx/ here is the other style-sheet:  http://jsfiddle.net/jzeig1/kzue4z75/   The above is the overall structure of nav and subNav structure

Comment: @emmanuel Hay, thanks for your help.  I have most of the code laid out, when I hover over subNav li the sub menu and the top level menu expands to the width of the items in the sub menu.  If I could get the subNav:li to line up vertically, that might help.  TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution to the above problem

```
 #nav li.subNav:hover ul li {
      visibility: visible;
      width:  171px;
      padding: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      float: none !important;
      display: block !important;
  }
```

I also found a way to keep the menu - once visible - from moving 'body #main' down the page

```
  #nav li.subNav ul {
       display: block;
       visibility: hidden;
       position: absolute;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `float:left` form `#nav li.subNav:hover ul li`

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vu0t6jfj/2/)

```
#nav li.subNav:hover ul li {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}
```

also remove default `margin` and `padding` which is give by browsers

```
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

you can also use universal selector to remove default styles of all elements given by browser

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: I'm still trying to get the li underneath top level menu to line up vertically.  Please take a look at the code in the previously commented statement and let me know if you see something missing or out of place